# How to save to CSV instead of printing to terminal Selenium webscrape data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, formatting, export-to-csv

I was finally able to scrape data from the website! And also print out the Headlines and Dates to the terminal. But I want to have it saved to a CSV file with a column for the headlines and a column for the dates. How do I do that?

My codes attached below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options=options,
    executable_path=r"//usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/81.0.4044.69/chromedriver")

driver.get(
    "https://www.nytimes.com/search?dropmab=true&endDate=20180111&query=nyc&sections=New%20York%7Cnyt%3A%2F%2Fsection%2F39480374-66d3-5603-9ce1-58cfa12988e2&sort=best&startDate=20180107")

myLength = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//figure[@class='css-tap2ym']//following::a[1]"))))

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='css-vsuiox']//button[@data-testid='search-show-more-button']"))).click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//figure[@class='css-tap2ym']//following::a[1]")) > myLength)
    titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//figure[@class='css-tap2ym']//following::a[1]")

    myLength = len(titles)
except TimeoutException:
    break

headlines_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="css-16nhkrn"]')
headlines = [x.text for x in eheadlines_element]
print('headlines:')
print(headlines, '\n')

dates_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//time[@class='css-17ubb9w']")
dates = [x.text for x in dates_element]
print("dates:")
print(dates, '\n')

for headlines, dates in zip(headlines, dates):
    print("Headlines : Dates")
    print(headlines + ": " + dates, '\n')

driver.quit()
```

It's that last bit of code that gets the headline and the dates. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write the data to the csv file.

**Use:**

```
with open("your_csv_file", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Headlines", "Dates"]) # --> Write header
    for h, d in zip(headlines, dates):
        writer.writerow([h, d]) # --> Write data
```

Comment: I get NameError: name 'csv' is not defined

Comment: I just added import csv sorry

Comment: @shubbbby if this answered  your question you may accept it

Comment: I am getting an error where it saves vertically [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfTn5.png] 
I added the code to the bottom of my code like this [https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQwBp.png]

Comment: @shubbbby You have to replace `for headlines, dates`  with `for h, d`  in all forloops

Comment: That's because you already have a list named `headlines` and `dates` defined in your code and using them as variables of iteration will produce undesirable effects.